# Application is suddently not compatible with tablets on Google Play

Tags: android, compatibility, tablet

my application was "visible" on Google play. I did not make any changes (I did not upload new apk) and application is suddently not compatible with tablets. Thanks for any help.

Look at very simple manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="fly.is.fun.unlocker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="fly.is.fun.unlocker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Agree with @GaryWong, there's no reason you should be targeting API 7. You're throwing away hardware acceleration among other things.

Answer (score 2):

Please check whether it's not visible on any device or some specific devices.

I had the same problem. But that was specific to Tab2.
Because I was using CAMERA permissions and Tab2 doesn't have autofocus for camera.

So I added following line in AndroidManifest file and then uploaded new apk to market.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

Now it's visible in Google play.

Also check [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - but I do not use any camera, gsm, ets - nothing

Comment: Have you checked whether it's not visible on any device or some specific devices?

Comment: There are only a few lines in java file.
PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);

Comment: When I checked it it Google Play developer console: Supported devices 2931, exclude devices 0

Comment: That had happened with me too. [FLY is FUN unlocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fly.is.fun.unlocker) is this your app??

Comment: Yes. This is my application (just unlocker) for FLY is FUN.

Comment: I checked it on some devices. I can see it on phone but not on tablets. You are not using any permission, no features or other filters; still Google play is not showing your app. Better contact support team.

Comment: Please check [this link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) Specifically **Testing the features required by your application** this heading. Try this and post the output of `$ aapt` command

Comment: Thanks Napster, I am trying to change android:targetSdkVersion from 7 to 17. Waiting no when new version will be on Google Play...

Comment: android:targetSdkVersion="17" solved the compatability problem, but new problem occurs: Menu button missing :-(

Answer (score 1):

In developer console, you only can see small, normal, large. You may try to add android:targetSdkVersion with a value higher or equal to 11